# Process.Start application was unable to start correctly w/ DTExec

Tags: ssis, dtexec

I am writing a tool that allows a DBA to remotely run an SSIS package.  The application is an XBAP and has been deployed to a SQL Server, with the SSIS package on the same server.  I achieve the remote calling of the SSIS package by running DTExec remotely on the server (I open the servers DTExec utility, not a local version) running as another user using Process.Start.

Here is the issue that I'm getting.  When running the application (from the server) from my desktop it works absolutely fine.  DTExec is started and the SSIS package is executed.  However, when I go to a different computer within our same network, I receive the error

```
The application was unable to start correctly (0xc0000143). Click OK to close the application.
```

This has happened on multiple computers, but for some reason works from mine.

The only difference between the two computers, is that mine has a version of SQL Server developer on it (meaning I have a local DTExec tool - however I am **not** calling this tool, the path is to \\server\Microsoft SQL Server...\DTExec.exe).

Does anyone have any idea what's going on here?

Comment: Please use tags properly to send your question to the right group. This question is related to SSIS but not sql-server and c#.

Comment: Oh okay, but I'm using Process.Start which is a C# command is it not?  And the application is hosted on sql-server, that has nothing to do with it?  Additionally, the DTExec utility is SQLServer specific...

Comment: You may use C# or Command Line or whatever but the issues is related DTExec not your C# code. Looks like there is no need to have knowledge on C# to answer your question. even it might be sql server installation or network , but not c#

Comment: Figured out the issue, it was because I was trying to run the process as another user using the StartInfo of Process.Start. The only changed code was C#.  While I appreciate you attempting to help the community, excluding a possibility when it is clearly a part of the problem at hand does not help to solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer via this blog post: http://asprosys.blogspot.ca/2009/03/perils-and-pitfalls-of-launching.html

Adding Credentials to the Process.StartInfo requires have permissions on the local machine as well as the server where the application is running and where the application you are attempting to run is found.